# Storing UTF-8 characters in the MySQL data-base

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to initialize the MySQL data-base relation by words written in Polish language using Java programming language.

This is the line of code:

```
db.executeQuery("create table "+schema+".category_"+globalId.split("-")[1]+"( id int not null unique, cName varchar(40) not null, primary key (id)) default character set =utf8 collate= utf8_bin;"
```

It works with German or Swedish language, that is the special characters for that language are stored  in data-base as it supposed to be (correct symbols). But when you are trying to write Polish language words it shows ????? instead of special characters for that language.

The same things happens when you are trying to write Chinese letter (you see ??????). I updated character set to bgk or big5, but that did not change anything.

What is the problem?
Cheers

Comment: what is your table's collation?

Comment: where are you viewing the records?? are you sure they are not stored well?

Comment: I view my records on MySQL Workbench app. In the place of special characters (Polish language symbols) I am seeing ?????? Collation as shown in the code above: default character set =utf8 collate= utf8_bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the character set (and maybe collation too) of your database.
See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html) for the documentation. This link is for mysql 5.0, but I think it is very similar in other versions too.

For example:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name
[[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
[[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]
```

These values that you setup for the database are then used as default for each `create table` statement. You can also override these values for individual tables.

**Update:**
Here is a better [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.htmlb). It lists the supported character sets in mysql 5.5. I recommend that you use utf8 character set.

Comment: No, it does not help. I changed the character set and collation of data-base. As shown in the code I specified those things there too. Though on utf8 I can see Polish language characters.

Comment: Changing the default charset/collation of the database will not help as charsets are defined on a per-table (or indeed, per-column if wanted) basis. The OP may need to use ALTER TABLE to change the tables.

Comment: There is one more thing. Those words in Polish language I receive over Internet encoded in XML. I outputted words on console (NetBeans) and I still see ???????? (question marks). But when you output something written in German language you see correct symbols. Maybe this is problem somewhere else. I might receive  question marks but not characters.

Comment: I do not need to alter tables. I simply delete them and then create new one with needed char set and collation.

Comment: alter or create - it doesn't matter, you need to adjust it to your specific scenario. Of course that altering the character set for the db won't affect already existing tables. As for netbeans, you need to check the character encoding of the netbeans console (at least that's how it works in Eclipse, I expect it to be similar)